# Update each user in nodejs app based on time interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node.js express app with MongoDB database and what I want is to be able to update the database based on time
Interval. For example
Increase a number field automatically every 7 days for each user based on an activation date set on each document.
Please how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron jobs for that.
A cron job used for scheduling tasks to be executed sometime in the future at specific time interval.

Find out more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron):

You will schedule a cron job that will run once in a day and you will add your code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The [What are Database Triggers?](https://www.mongodb.com/features/database-triggers) documentation indicates triggers, however it's not clear if that available on the free Community Edition, or only on their hosted Atlas offering. If you can't figure out a Mongo trigger solution, you would have to code a controller in Node.js based on `.setInterval` to fetch user creation date(s) then insert whatever update(s) you want on the user(s).

> #### Types of Database Triggers MongoDB provides three types of triggers:
>
> - Database Triggers: Perform some type of action when a document is updated, added, or removed.
> - **Scheduled Triggers**: Scheduled actions that occur at a specific time or set interval. MongoDB Atlas leverages an intuitive approach to
>   scheduling triggers using the CRON expression language. These types of
>   triggers can be as simple as running a daily clean-up process of
>   temporary records, to generate a minute-by-minute report on
>   transaction anomalies.
> - Authentication Triggers (Realm only): Actions that happen when creating or deleting a user or on login into MongoDB. These types of
>   triggers are for performing user maintenance or user audit tracking
>   for Realm apps.